# Selenium not finding element on XPATH on certain page

Tags: python, selenium

### I want to press the Login Button on the site https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/ using selenium, I'm passing the XPATH of the Element that I select from inspect, but it doesnt work

#### text base HTML:

```
<divclass="hmMainHeaderRHSLoggedOutWide_Login">Login</div>
```

#### XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div
```

#### Myscript.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/')
TIME_TO_LOAD = 10
try:
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, TIME_TO_LOAD).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div'))
    )
finally:
   driver.quit()
```

The button of the page that i want to click:
[image: Page to edit]

The text base HTML:< div class="hmMainHeaderRHSLoggedOutWide_Login">Login</ div>

Comment: _**Access Denied**_ Can you update the question with the text based HTML of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below `xpath`

```
"//*[normalize-space(text())='Login']"
```

Or

```
"//*[contains(text(),'Login')]"
```

to click on button

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Login')]")

button.click()
```

Also, provide the more info to understand the question clearly.

Comment: It works, the element was found, but I dont know how to click on the element, can you provide more code?

Comment: You can do it like. like
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Login')]")

button.click()

If this solve your question, so please accept the answer. Also updated the answer too.

Comment: It gives the error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

Always try to point out the elements you want using something that is most likely to stay the same every time you load the page, so the selector for the element you want should be using something unique, like "id" or "class", because the hierarchy is most likely to change.

In this case, I used the class "hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutWide_Login" to locate the element.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/')
TIME_TO_LOAD = 10

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, TIME_TO_LOAD).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutWide_Login "]')
        )
    )
    print(element.text)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: it still didnt work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The item wasn't found, it sends the error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException